# How to append data to table using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, data-binding

I've one HTML table:

```
<table id="tableOrderDetail" class="table-striped table-bordered" style="align: center; width: 100%;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="5%">Sr. No.</th>
    <th width="25%">Product Name</th>
    <th width="12%" class="center">No Of Carton</th>
    <th width="12%" class="center">Quantity</th>
    <th width="12%" class="center">Original Price</th>
    <th width="12%" class="center">Order Price</th>
    <th width="10%" class="center">Discount</th>
    <th width="12%" class="center">Total Price</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td width="25%" class="ProductName"></td>
    <td width="12%" class="NoOfCarton"></td>
    <td width="12%" class="ProductQuantity"></td>
    <td width="12%" class="OriginalPrice"></td>
    <td width="12%" class="OrderPrice"></td>
    <td width="10%" class="Discount"></td>
    <td width="12%" class="TotalPrice"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Now I've to append all data to the table, I've tried like following:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../handlers/DisplaySpecificOrderDetail.ashx?OrderId=" + Orderid, //+ "tk=" + Date.toLocaleTimeString()
                data: "{ OrderId: " + Orderid + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: "true",
                cache: "false",
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#tableOrderDetail tbody").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();

                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            //setting the data in first row itself
                            setDataOnRow($("#tableOrderDetail tbody").find("tr").first(), v);
                        } else {
                            //clonning the first row and setting data over it and then appending in tbody
                            var clonnedRow = $($("#tableOrderDetail tbody").find("tr").first()).clone();
                            setDataOnRow(clonnedRow, v);
                            $("#tableOrderDetail tbody").append(clonnedRow);
                        }
                     });         
                   }); 

function setDataOnRow(rowObject, v) {
               // debugger
                $(rowObject).find(".ProductName").html(v.ProductName);
                $(rowObject).find(".NoOfCarton").html(v.NoOfCarton);
                $(rowObject).find(".ProductQuantity").html(v.ProductQuantity);
                $(rowObject).find(".OriginalPrice").html(v.OriginalPrice);
                $(rowObject).find(".OrderPrice").html(v.OrderPrice);
                $(rowObject).find(".Discount").html(v.Discount);
                $(rowObject).find(".TotalPrice").html(v.TotalPrice);
            }
```

It's successfully bind data to the table.

But for more than one record it's get only last record.(override)
How can i bind all rows with table?

**EDIT 1:**

I used `.append()` but it gives me both record in one row.. how can i separate it in different row?

**EDIT 2:** Here is my handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            long OrderId;
            Result res = new Result();    
            long.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["OrderId"].ToString(), out OrderId);

            JavaScriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            SpecificOrderDetailManagement specificordMgr = new SpecificOrderDetailManagement();

                res = specificordMgr.GetOrderDetailOrderID(OrderId);
                context.Response.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res.ListObject));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Edit 3: Screen
[image]

Comment: use .append() insted of .html()

Comment: Only use `.html()` if you're actually modifying html, otherwise use `text()`. Chris is right though, you want `.append()` here

Comment: I use `.append()` but it gives me both record in one row.. how can i separate it in different row?

Comment: @Chris, question updated

Comment: .append(ProductQuantity + "<br>"); or use any other html tag like: .append("<p>" + ProductQuantity + "</p>");

Comment: @Chris, It's not working properly, if my `ProductQuantity` is `33` then it's displaying `3` in one row  and other `3` in secod row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically `clone` the first row present in `tbody` and then `append` it back in table with newer row data like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var testData = [{
    "ProductName": "AAA",
    "NoOfCarton": 10
  }, {
    "ProductName": "BBB",
    "NoOfCarton": 20
  }];

  $("#tableOrderDetail tbody").find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); //remove all old rows except first one

  $.each(testData, function(i, v) {

    if (i == 0) {
      //setting the data in first row itself
      setDataOnRow($("#tableOrderDetail tbody").find("tr").first(), v);

    } else {

      //clonning the first row and setting data over it and then appending in tbody
      var clonnedRow = $($("#tableOrderDetail tbody").find("tr").first()).clone();
      setDataOnRow(clonnedRow, v);

      $("#tableOrderDetail tbody").append(clonnedRow);

    }
  });

});

//set the data in row
function setDataOnRow(rowObject, v) {
  var test = v.ProductName;
  var NoOfCarton = v.NoOfCarton;
  $(rowObject).find(".ProductName").html(test);
  $(rowObject).find(".NoOfCarton").html(NoOfCarton);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableOrderDetail" class="table-striped table-bordered" style="align: center; width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="25%">Product Name</th>
      <th width="12%" class="center">No Of Carton</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td width="25%" class="ProductName">test</td>
      <td width="12%" class="NoOfCarton">test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

**Note:** for simplicity I am just showing 2 columns. Please modify it according to your number of columns.

Comment: It's working as expected, but the problem is it's working for only first time. I've numbers of button in my grid, when user click on first then data came accordingly, but if user clicked on second time on other button then it's displaying `test` `test`

Comment: @user6689472 - could you please try now. I have updated the answer and added one line just before `$.each(testData,`. Please try that in your code.

Comment: No luck, displaying same `test` `test`

Comment: I can't guess what would be wrong at your end. Is it possible to create a fiddle or snippet here which will show the issue you are facing?

Comment: Note: I'm doing this on an ajax success, and need to bind each time new data.

Comment: So for demo purpose on each button click we can use `var testData` and `var testData_1` and so on. Can you create demo such like this?

Comment: *Is it possible to create a fiddle or snippet* Actually, I've repeater control for orders and and each row has a button, when user click on button then accordingly `orderId` fetch data from database and bind to the table.

Comment: *Can you create demo such like this?* let me try.

Comment: I've tried to create demo, in which i take 2 buttons and passed different data on click, but it's working totally fine.

Comment: How can I check now, can you please give me suggestion, I'm stuck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123914/discussion-between-vijayp-and-user6689472).

Comment: Added handler to the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

in your code your are not creating any `<tr>` or `<td>` element you are just replacing the existing element's html content.

Append the table row after `tbody` for every set of data received by ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../handlers/DisplaySpecificOrderDetail.ashx?OrderId=" + Orderid, //+ "tk=" + Date.toLocaleTimeString()
    data: "{ OrderId: " + Orderid + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: "true",
    cache: "false",
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            $('#tableOrderDetail').find('tbody')
                .append('<tr>').append('<td width="25%" class="ProductName">' + v.ProductName + '</td>')
                .append('<td width="25%" class="NoOfCarton">' + v.NoOfCarton + '</td>')
                .append('<td width="25%" class="ProductQuantity">' + v.ProductQuantity + '</td>')
                .append('<td width="25%" class="OriginalPrice">' + v.OriginalPrice + '</td>')
                .append('<td width="25%" class="OrderPrice">' + v.OrderPrice + '</td>')
                .append('<td width="25%" class="Discount">' + v.Discount + '</td>')
                .append('<td width="25%" class="TotalPrice">' + v.TotalPrice + '</td>')
                .append('<tr>');
        });
    }
});
```