# how to display data by using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Hi everyone I am a facing one issue in ajax I want to display this data as a table in html how can I extract this data and display it in html table form it is a just dummy data otherwise it have lots of object plus nested object please help me.

JSON DATA:

```
{
    "FullName":"shahrushabh",
    "description":"this is demo person register",  
    "Address1":"b\/1",
    "Area":"Sabarmati",
    "status":"active",
    "Thumb":"0",
    "checkbox":
    [
        {"ID":"1","UniqueID":"617993","Product":"electronics","Image":"617993\/alphansomangolips.jpg"},
        {"ID":"2","UniqueID":"617993","Product":"Home Decor","Image":"617993\/banana.jpg"}
    ]
}
```

AJAX CODE:

```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/myad",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
              var jsonobject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              alert("hi");
              $.each(jsonobject, function(key, value){
                console.log(value.FullName);
                $.each(value.checkbox , function(k, val){
                  console.log(val);
                })
              })
            }
           });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: This may helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39617796/4753489

Comment: Sorry this is a not a helpful for me

Comment: Why? is not you looking for?

Comment: Sorry there is a used only one each function when here is a nested object can you please help me?  Please answer this question. If you know.

Comment: Show your code, what you've tried so far?

Comment: Which code Php, Ajax, or html?

Comment: *//what to write here?* this code

Comment: Sorry sorry it is a really useful thanks for it.

Comment: See, whenever you ask a question, you should show your tired, and after where you stuck. you can't not directly asking for the code. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry man it is a my mistake

Comment: It's okay, you're beginner. So i just inform you. add your tried code to the question, will help you to sort out your problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed from your question is you have nested object, below code is to use each for nested object.

```
//Main loop
$.each(jsonObject, function(key, value){
  console.log(value.FullName);
  //Inner loop for check box for each user
  $.each(value.checkbox, function(k, val){
    console.log(val);
  })
});
```

Please make sure that you've read [Official each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) before using it.

**EDIT**

Check response is an array or not before iteration.

```
if (!$.isArray(jsonObject)) {
    jsonObject = [jsonObject];
}

$.each(jsonObject, function(key, value){
  console.log("FULL NAME " + value.FullName);
  $.each(value.checkbox, function(k, val){
    console.log("ID" + " " + val.ID);
  });
});
```

```js
var jsonObject = [
    {
      "FullName":"shahrushabh",
      "description":"this is demo person register",  
      "Address1":"b\/1",
      "Area":"Sabarmati",
      "status":"active",
      "Thumb":"0",
      "checkbox":
      [
          {"ID":"1","UniqueID":"617993","Product":"electronics","Image":"617993\/alphansomangolips.jpg"},
          {"ID":"2","UniqueID":"617993","Product":"Home Decor","Image":"617993\/banana.jpg"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "FullName":"shahrushabh",
      "description":"this is demo person register",  
      "Address1":"b\/1",
      "Area":"Sabarmati",
      "status":"active",
      "Thumb":"0",
      "checkbox":
      [
        {"ID":"1","UniqueID":"617993","Product":"electronics","Image":"617993\/alphansomangolips.jpg"},
        {"ID":"2","UniqueID":"617993","Product":"Home Decor","Image":"617993\/banana.jpg"}
      ]
    }
 ];

//console.log(jsonObject);
$.each(jsonObject, function(key, value){
  console.log(value.FullName);
  $.each(value.checkbox, function(k, val){
    console.log(val);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/myad",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data){
                  $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    console.log(value.FullName);
                    $.each(value.checkbox , function(k, val){
                      console.log(val);
                    })
                  })
                }
               });
           });
        </script>

Comment: it appearing json data

Comment: You need to parse your json data before each loop. i.e. 
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data); , Let me know if you still finds any problem ?

Comment: Still it have a issue even not appearing alert

Comment: var jsonobject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                  alert("hi");
                  $.each(jsonobject, function(key, value){

Comment: Can you update your code or create jsfiddle so I can check your problem ?

Comment: Yes wait only 2 minutes

Comment: I assumed that your ajax call code is in your PHP file, see the console if you're getting any errors.

Comment: No there is no any error there displaying json giving json data that I mentioned on question

Comment: Where exactly you're getting any problem ? displaying data ? can you do console in each loop s?

Comment: Now what to do?

Comment: Try var data = JSON.stringify(data) instead of jQuery.parseJSON(data) and tell me what exactly you're facing.

Comment: I tried each loop in alert function but it giving undefined I think error in jquery.

Comment: Even alert hi is not executing it means error in jquery not in php.

Comment: After a removing line of parseJSON it appearing hi massage.

Comment: JSON.stringify definitely works for you, now what's error you're getting in console ? are you able to console every loop data ?  Or can make your ajax URL live so I can provide you code for the same.

Comment: It working when I am a replacing value.FullName with data.FullName.

Comment: No I written spelling of value.FullName it is a right or wrong?

Comment: Man please help me

Comment: Just update your code with the current code, including what you're getting in console as object from ajax. I will check and let me know in sometime

Comment: If I will upload this files on server than can you reply me?

Comment: Yes I will check it

Comment: After a replacing value with data than it successfully running and displaying data

Comment: So is there any problems now ?

Comment: Go to sale.coupsoft.com it is a url where I uploaded file

Comment: Without credential I can't do anything, Just update your code with current code and what you're getting in console in response of ajax call, then I will check that.

Comment: what you're doing in jquery and response of ajax call,

Comment: I am a doing as you mentioned

Comment: But please go on my website and inspect with firebug lite and check my jquery code please inform if I made any mistakes in coding.

Comment: You have single record or your might have multiple records in that json object ?

Comment: @shahrushabh: I've updated my answer, please use this code now, your response was not an array from ajax, it was an object. let me know if you still find any problem.

Comment: Glad to see that :)

Comment: But still few issues can you resolve my other issues? Definitely it working fine.

Comment: what are they ?

Comment: Now I want to display it by using html. I know that I just need to select ID and than after use a function .html but this html code is complicated.

Comment: You can just do the .append function to append to the table in the HTML, you can also do some googling on that.

Comment: Thanks man I not want to appear in table form I want to make better look for it.

Comment: Better means ? what exactly you're try to do ?